# First author in bibliography in lastname, firstname but subsequent authors as firstname lastname

Tags: biblatex, sorting, legal-style

The Australian Legal Citation Guide v3 states that for a bibliography, the entry for a book should have the first author appear as lastname, firstname and then all subsequent authors appear as firstname lastname, e.g.

> Cook, Catriona, Robin Creyke and Robert Geddes

The macro below does this by printing out the first author entry in last, first order and then adding a comma and a space if there is no 'et al' following.  I find this doesn't work though.  I'm trying to use the `\ifandothers` test but it seems always to return false.  So for an 'et al' entry I end up with:

> Cook, Catriona,  et al

I am trying to do this with the macro below.  I've been at it for hours and I'm brand new to LaTeX and biblatex so I'm pulling what hair I have left out in frustration.

Is the macro I am using correct?  I suspect this is a noob error.  I would appreciate any help.

PS: I'm not even up to the editor part of the macro yet.

PPS: This code comes from aglc2.cbx which is part of Will Hardy's AGLC style and is posted at http://github.com/willhardy/aglc

```
\newbibmacro{author/editor:lastnamefirst}{%
\ifthenelse{\ifuseauthor\AND\NOT\ifnameundef{author}}%
    {\ifuseauthor{%
    \ifandothers{author}{%
        \printnames[sortname][1-1]{author}%
        \printnames[default][2-2]{author}%
    } {%
        \printnames[sortname][1-1]{author}%
        \addcomma\addspace%
        \printnames[default][2-3]{author}%
        }%
    }{}}%
    {\ifthenelse{\ifuseeditor\AND\NOT\ifnameundef{editor}}{\printnames[sortname]{editor}}{}}%
}
```

UPDATE: In response to @lockstep's suggestion here is some code that shows that I could not get \DeclareNameAlias to work:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[style=aglc2,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first/first-last}
\bibliography{week1}

\begin{document}
Test citations here:\footcite{ldtl7} and here:\footcite{ldtl7a}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here's the bib file:

```
@BOOK{ldtl7,
  year       = 2009,
  author     = {Catriona Cook and Robin Creyke and Robert Geddes and David Hamer},
  title      = {Laying Down the Law},
  edition    = 7,
  publisher  = {LexisNexis Butterworths}
}
@BOOK{ldtl7a,
  year       = 2009,
  author     = {Catriona Cook and Robin Creyke and Robert Geddes},
  title      = {Laying Down the Law2},
  edition    = 7,
  publisher  = {LexisNexis Butterworths}
}
```

Here's the output:

```
References
Cook, Catriona, Robin Creyke and Robert Geddes, Laying Down the Law2 (LexisNexis Butterworths, 7th ed, 2009)
Cook, Catriona, Robin Creyke et al, Robert Geddes, Laying Down the Law (LexisNexis Butterworths, 7th ed, 2009)
```

And in the footnotes:

```
1 Cook, Catriona, Robin Creyke et al, Robert Geddes, Laying Down the Law (LexisNexis Butterworths, 7th ed, 2009).
2 Cook, Catriona, Robin Creyke and Robert Geddes, Laying Down the Law2 (LexisNexis Butterworths, 7th ed, 2009).
```

Comment: Seamus, I haven't done this because I want 'et al' to be printed if there's more than 3 authors.  But at the moment I get "Lastname, Firstname,  et al" instead of "Lastname, Firstname et al" (extra comma and space inserted)

Comment: You should become a member of the panel that decides on the Australian Legal Citation Guide and make them abolish this guideline.

Comment: @Mark: It is unusual around here to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your name below it) or to have any greeting.

Comment: So the question isn't about the order of the listed authors names at all? It's about getting rid of a comma from a bibliography entry? Perhaps you could change the title to reflect this?

Comment: @Mark: `maxnames=3` (or `\printbibliography[maxnames=3]`) should do the trick, indeed (though this option is not called “maxauthors”). There should be no comma before the “et al.” Please create a minimal example if the behaviour is different for you.

Comment: I've removed the `author` tag because it is normally used for title pages, not for bibliographies/citations. This is a close case, though.

Comment: @domwass:  Using the default code gives me: "Catriona Cook, Robin Creyke and Robert Geddes" but what I want is "Cook, Catriona, Robin Creyke and Robert Geddes".  Also if the author list is > 3 then I want "Cook, Catriona et al".  My macro above gives me what I want if there are < 3 authors but for > 3 I get "Cook, Catriona,  et al" (extra comma and space).

Comment: @Mark can you edit your question so that it explains the problem you actually want fixed? (i.e. talk about the problem as you do in the comment above this one.)

Comment: @Mark: I think the problem is that you've done some rather 'hacky' things with the author-formatting code in `aglc2`. I'd suggest you might want to take a bit of a step back, and work through your `.bbx` and `.cbx` files from scratch. Build up slowly, starting by loading some standard `biblatex` ones, and test at each stage.

Comment: @Joseph (& @lockstep) I think you're right.  I started playing with DeclareNameFormats yesterday to find there's a format in TFM that does at least part of what I want.  So what I'll do is spend the next few days going thru the formats and reconstructing them.  I'll post what I find.

Answer (score 5):

It shouldn't be necessary to define new macros. Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first/first-last}%
}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
%   \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}% DELETED
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest.bib}
@book{CCG01,
  author = {Cook, Catriona and Creyke, Robin and Geddes, Robert},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblatextest.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{CCG01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Example updated to use `\AtBeginBibliography`.

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: @lockstep: @Mark complained about the comma before “et al.” which should not be there with standard biblatex settings. But if he meant the comma before the “and”, then you’re right.

Comment: @lockstep: I just ran your file and it works.  I added an extra author and it formats this correctly too.  But I have no idea how it works!  Could you explain it?

Comment: @Mark: I didn't use the AGLC styles but simply hoped they would work similar to the built-in styles. `\DeclareNameAlias` is responsible for switching first and last names, while `\finalnamedelim` is the macro responsible for typesetting a comma plus "and" before the last author (or, as redefined, typesetting only "and").

Comment: @lockstep: while your sample works (marvellously) I can't seem to transplant it into the AGLC style.  I added the `\DeclareNameAlias` and `\finalnamedelim` to aglc2.cbx and after to aglc2.bbx.  I then reverted to using the standard `author/editor` macro for printing my book entries.  The spacing is good and the comma has gone but now the authors' names appear as firstname lastname instead of lastname firstname eg: "Catriona Cook, Robin Creyke..." instead of "Cook, Catriona, Robin Crekye...".

Comment: @lockstep:   I hope you don't mind but I've made the versions of aglc2.?bx available for you to check out.  Here are [aglc2.cbx](https://files.me.com/mark_ferraretto/rulv9x) and [aglc2.bbx](https://files.me.com/mark_ferraretto/xem74l).  I would appreciate you taking a look.  I hope that's OK.

Comment: @Mark: I've tested my minimal example with `[style=aglc2]` now. It yields the output desired by you if you just add the line with `\DeclareNameAlias`. But you have to add it either in the preamble of your document or in the configuration file `biblatex.cfg` (which is empty by default). Adding it at the begin of `aglc2.bbx` or `ablc2.cbx` (as I suspect you did) may not be sufficient, as the code may be overriden.

Comment: @lockstep: I get this: `Cook, Catriona, Robin Creyke et al, Robert Geddes,...` ie: the 'et al' is in the wrong place.  Also Catriona Cook appears as 'Cook, Catriona' in a `\footcite{}` now whereas previously she was appearing as 'Catriona Cook' (which is what I want ie: Firstname Lastname in the footcites and Lastname, Firstname in the bibliography)

Comment: @Mark: I confess that I'm not familiar with the intricacies of `\DeclareNameAlias`, and so may have blundered. On the other hand, it is hard to offer help based on code snippets. Please edit your question and include a compilable (!) minimal example that shows the problematic behaviour. I suggest you start with my examle (plus `[style=aglc2]`).

Comment: @lockstep I updated my original post with the code snippet and output.

Comment: @Mark: Basically, you should folllow the advice @Joseph Wright gave in the comment to your original question. However, I updated my example to show a (hacky?) way how to change `\DeclareNameAlias` only for the bibliography. (I used one of the standard styles that uses `\footcite`.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it although I'm not entirely sure why.  It seems there were two issues to solve.  The first one was what I asked ie: how to have only the first author appear as last-first with subsequent authors appear first-last.  To fix this I altered the `sortname` `DeclareNameFormat` in aglc2.cbx.  It now looks like this:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{%
        \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}
                {
                        \usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
                        \usebibmacro{name:andothers}
                } 
                {
                        \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>1\and\value{listtotal}>\value{liststop}}
                        {}
                        {%
                            \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
                        }%
                }
}
```

I'm pretty confident this is a decent solution.

The strange bit is how I fixed the 'et al' placement.  I know what I did but I don't know why it works.  I had to make two changes.  The first was to delete this macro:

```
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% 
  \ifthenelse{\value{listtotal}>\value{liststop}\AND\value{listcount}=2\AND\ifmorenames}%
    {\addspace\bibstring{andothers}}%
    {}}
```

The existence of this macro seemed to be the cause of not having 'et al' printed at all.

The second change was to change this:

```
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifuseauthor
    {\printnames[][1-3]{author}}
    {}}
```

to this

```
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifuseauthor
    {\printnames{author}}
    {}}
```

This seemed to be the cause of having 'et al' appear after the second author instead of after the first.  Why is beyond me.  But now that these changes are made, the style seems to be working properly.

So I think I'm there!  I'd love to find out more about those last two changes so they don't bite me later but at least I'm where I want to be... for now.

Thanks to everyone who helped.  Having the discussion with you all is what made this possible.  I appreciate your guidance.